# Error: Gradle DSL method not found: compile()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF6id.jpg)

Hello, we've created an android app for our site, but now you want to turn it into an APK, but I've encountered the following error and do not let me move on with the compilation.

```
Error:(60, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
    Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Template' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
    <a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'Template' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
    <a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
    <a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Here it's the build.gradle (Project: Template)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

ext {
    supportlib_version = '26.0.2'
    gps_version = '11.2.0'
}

//Ensure that all dependencies use the same version of the Android Support library
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$supportlib_version"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$gps_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and second build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.mayermayer.transport'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        //Optionally configure your OneSignal IDs below
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    jcenter();
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.0.3'
    //TV
    compile 'com.cleveroad:audiovisualization:1.0.0'
    //Radio
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    //WC
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0,4.0.0)'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.apg-mobile:android-round-textview:v0.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    //WC
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.3'
    //TV & Radio
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportlib_version" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gps_version" compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Am I wrong somewhere? I use Android Studio 2.3.3 latest version.

Can you please help me? Have you met this error? I wish you a beautiful day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move this line in different lines:

```
    //TV & Radio
   compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportlib_version" compile "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportlib_version" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gps_version" compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
```

You can't use `compile` in this way.
Use this:

```
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version" 
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version" 
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version" 
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version" 
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportlib_version" 
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportlib_version" 
compile "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportlib_version" 
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version" 
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version" 
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gps_version" 
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
```

Comment: Hi @JohannMayer if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change below version in your `Gradle-wrapper.properties` or you need to update **Gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```